# Can you help me to identify this unknown notation in his arm?

Tags: notation

[image]

What's this in his arm? I've never seen such notation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This look like Frege's "[Begriffsschrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffsschrift)". Try to translate it using the syntax desciption in the Wikipedia article I linked.